# How to access data in this multidimensional json array?

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array

For some reason, I'm having a hard time accessing a multidimensional array returned by an api call. I've spent hours trying different outcomes without success. I think I need a second pair of eyes. I'm trying to access the coordinates, latitude and longitude of the address. I tried with `data.features.geometry.coordinates` and I get

> error : geometry is undefined

Ajax api call :

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/access_token',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType:'json',
                success: function(data)
                {

                console.log(data);

                }
            });
```

Console returns this (sorry big data) :

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "address.2829218120531924",
            "type": "Feature",
            "place_type": [
                "address"
            ],
            "relevance": 1,
            "properties": {
                "accuracy": "rooftop"
            },
            "text": "Southwest 59th Court",
            "place_name": "7313 Southwest 59th Court, Miami, Florida 33143, United States",
            "matching_place_name": "7313 Southwest 59th Court, Miami, Florida 33143, United States of America",
            "center": [
                -80.290092,
                25.70304
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -80.290092,
                    25.70304
                ]
            },
            "address": "7313",
            "context": [
                {
                    "id": "neighborhood.277794",
                    "text": "South Miami"
                },
                {
                    "id": "postcode.9047361780999760",
                    "text": "33143"
                },
                {
                    "id": "place.9791754866122320",
                    "wikidata": "Q8652",
                    "text": "Miami"
                },
                {
                    "id": "region.12218597351235010",
                    "short_code": "US-FL",
                    "wikidata": "Q812",
                    "text": "Florida"
                },
                {
                    "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                    "short_code": "us",
                    "wikidata": "Q30",
                    "text": "United States"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "address.4735143261475820",
            "type": "Feature",
            "place_type": [
                "address"
            ],
            "relevance": 0.836667,
            "properties": {
                "accuracy": "street"
            },
            "text": "Southwest 59th Court",
            "place_name": "Southwest 59th Court, Miami, Florida 33143, United States",
            "matching_place_name": "Southwest 59th Court, Miami, Florida 33143, United States of America",
            "center": [
                -80.2906123,
                25.7175916
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -80.2906123,
                    25.7175916
                ]
            },
            "context": [
                {
                    "id": "neighborhood.277794",
                    "text": "South Miami"
                },
                {
                    "id": "postcode.9047361780999760",
                    "text": "33143"
                },
                {
                    "id": "place.9791754866122320",
                    "wikidata": "Q8652",
                    "text": "Miami"
                },
                {
                    "id": "region.12218597351235010",
                    "short_code": "US-FL",
                    "wikidata": "Q812",
                    "text": "Florida"
                },
                {
                    "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                    "short_code": "us",
                    "wikidata": "Q30",
                    "text": "United States"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "address.3831267361566610",
            "type": "Feature",
            "place_type": [
                "address"
            ],
            "relevance": 0.801333,
            "properties": {
                "accuracy": "interpolated"
            },
            "text": "Southwest 59th Avenue",
            "place_name": "7313 Southwest 59th Avenue, Miami, Florida 33143, United States",
            "matching_place_name": "7313 Southwest 59th Avenue, Miami, Florida 33143, United States of America",
            "center": [
                -80.289343,
                25.704199
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -80.289343,
                    25.704199
                ],
                "interpolated": true
            },
            "address": "7313",
            "context": [
                {
                    "id": "neighborhood.277794",
                    "text": "South Miami"
                },
                {
                    "id": "postcode.9047361780999760",
                    "text": "33143"
                },
                {
                    "id": "place.9791754866122320",
                    "wikidata": "Q8652",
                    "text": "Miami"
                },
                {
                    "id": "region.12218597351235010",
                    "short_code": "US-FL",
                    "wikidata": "Q812",
                    "text": "Florida"
                },
                {
                    "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                    "short_code": "us",
                    "wikidata": "Q30",
                    "text": "United States"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "postcode.9047361780999760",
            "type": "Feature",
            "place_type": [
                "postcode"
            ],
            "relevance": 0.787778,
            "properties": {},
            "text": "33143",
            "place_name": "Miami, Florida 33143, United States",
            "matching_place_name": "Miami, Florida 33143, United States of America",
            "bbox": [
                -80.3349178558439,
                25.6880751353229,
                -80.2450230532034,
                25.7188419508551
            ],
            "center": [
                -80.29,
                25.71
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -80.29,
                    25.71
                ]
            },
            "context": [
                {
                    "id": "place.9791754866122320",
                    "wikidata": "Q8652",
                    "text": "Miami"
                },
                {
                    "id": "region.12218597351235010",
                    "short_code": "US-FL",
                    "wikidata": "Q812",
                    "text": "Florida"
                },
                {
                    "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                    "short_code": "us",
                    "wikidata": "Q30",
                    "text": "United States"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "address.7544455348675994",
            "type": "Feature",
            "place_type": [
                "address"
            ],
            "relevance": 0.755,
            "properties": {
                "accuracy": "street"
            },
            "text": "Southwest 59th Court",
            "place_name": "Southwest 59th Court, Miami, Florida 33156, United States",
            "matching_place_name": "Southwest 59th Court, Miami, Florida 33156, United States of America",
            "center": [
                -80.2890202,
                25.6464222
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -80.2890202,
                    25.6464222
                ]
            },
            "context": [
                {
                    "id": "neighborhood.270046",
                    "text": "Deering Bay"
                },
                {
                    "id": "postcode.9496629846896750",
                    "text": "33156"
                },
                {
                    "id": "place.9791754866122320",
                    "wikidata": "Q8652",
                    "text": "Miami"
                },
                {
                    "id": "region.12218597351235010",
                    "short_code": "US-FL",
                    "wikidata": "Q812",
                    "text": "Florida"
                },
                {
                    "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                    "short_code": "us",
                    "wikidata": "Q30",
                    "text": "United States"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `features` is an array. You need to access the object inside your array before accessing `geometry`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of reading up on JSON and accessing [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json#11922384).

So this works for me

```
data.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
```

Also this

```
data["features"][0]["geometry"]['coordinates'];
```